# OAuth2 login without browsing in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-analytics

I use [Google Analytics API Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/analytics/v3) in my Asp.net MVC project to get reports of google analytics service and show them in my asp.net mvc project. My project uses OAuth2 authentication for just one page ( AnalyticsController ).To authenticate that page , it browses automatically a google authentication OAuth2 page and i need to give my google username and password  to authenticate me ... is it possible to handle the OAuth2 authentication programmatically in c# instead of browsing a google authentication page ? if yes , How can i do that with  Google Analytics API Client Library for .NET

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please specify the proper terms?

Comment: @dikesh i use that google library to get info from google analytics service and show it in my asp.net project and i use  OAuth2 authentication for this reason .  when i brows analytics page ( AnalyticsController ) in my project , automatically it opens a new page which is related to google login form and i need to login and accept the Grant condition and then i can use my project normally . Giving grant or permission happens just once But what i need is , after once giving grant or permission , i do login  with google username password in c#

Comment: Understood. So when you authenticate your account, you must be receiving Access Token and Refresh Token, right?

Comment: @dikesh actually i don't do anything ... this process of authentication handles automatically by google analytics library . i use  CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET  in my codes .

Comment: @dikesh  But i think u are right !